# ERROR: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\....php on line 19

Tags: php

I keep on receiving an error message using `mysql_num_rows()`, can you help me figure out what went wrong on my code?

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
//check if the user press submit
if (isset($_POST['submit'] )) {

    $customer = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["username"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username='$customer' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
    // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
    $existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the row nums
    if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
         }
         $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
         $_SESSION["customer"] = $customer;
         $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
         header("location: index.php");
         exit();
    } else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="customer_login.php">Click Here</a>';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

I've tried `mysql_errno()` as you advised.. and it echo 1146

and when I search for that error it says that

```
1146: Table 'kossu.nonexistenttable' doesn't exist
```

But I don't know what it means... Please help.

Comment: `$sql` is probably false, which is why it is failing. Check the query is correct.

Comment: There might be an error in your sql syntax and mysql_query is returning false. Print out the entire query and paste it into phymyadmin (or similar) and see if it executes correctly.

Comment: @AllisonC i've try the sql syntax at mysql and it successfully returns the id.

Comment: Read one arbitrary answer below and then use `mysql_error()` to find out, what really happens with your query. There is no need to guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably `mysql_query()` failed. In this case it returns `false`. Use [mysql_error()](http://php.net/mysql-error) to find out, what happens.

Comment: hi KingCrunch i've tried to echo mysql_error() as you advice and it echo 1146, when i search for what it means it says that 1146: Table 'kossu.nonexistenttable' doesn't exist, can you help me cause i really have no idea what does this mean... i'v also tried the syntax of $sql to mysql and it successfully flash the column id please help thanx

Comment: @iamanaprentice: I really don't know, what I should say more. The table `kossu.nonexistenttable` does not exists. I think, its really obvious, what does this mean. In your case it seems, that there is no table `members` to query over. Additional I said `mysql_error()` and not `mysql_errno()`. With the first one you will receive a concrete error message instead of an unspecific error code. This is a little bit more useful than the example output you have taken from the PHP-manual ;)

Comment: @ KingCrunch... thank you very much because of mysql_error() i found out the my database were mispelled at my connection code :) thanks again

Answer (score 1):

When there is an error, `mysql_query()` returnse `false` instead of a resource object. Check the return value of `mysql_query()` before you pass it to `mysql_num_rows()`.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> Return Values
>
> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

So, you have an error. Use `mysql_error()` to find out what.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` failed. It returns `false`.To see the error use `mysql_error()`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you've not selected the right database. I encountered such a problem before and the error was the database I selected.

Answer (score 0):

When the MySQL query is executed it is expected to return the query result. It returns `False` if the query was not successfully executed. It seems that your query failed so it returned `False`. When you try to count rows with `mysql_num_rows()` to the failed query, it will definitely return error. There might be error in your query. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

The cause could be that the SQL query is using an incorrect database.  Use the fully-qualified table name, i.e. `databaseName.tableName`.

In your case:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM DBName.members WHERE username='$customer' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1");
```

where 'DBName' is your database name.