# Warning: mysql_fetch_row()/mysql_fetch_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to this.Even though I checked php.net for the functions  `mysql_fetch_row()` and `mysql_fetch_result()` I keep getting warnings

> expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

```
  <?php

 //code

 $sql1="SELECT * FROM $tblname WHERE USERNAME='$myusername' and    PASSWORD='$mypassword'";
 $result1=mysql_query($sql1);

 // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
 $count=mysql_num_rows($result1);
 // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

 if($count==1)
 {

 $sql2="SELECT CLIENT_ID FROM $tblname WHERE USERNAME='$myusername' and PASSWORD='$mypassword'";
 $result2=mysql_query($sql2); //THIS LINE!!!
 $cid=mysql_result($result2,$row2); //THIS LINE!!!

 // Register info
 $_SESSION['sessname'] = "$myusername";
 $_SESSION['sesspwd'] = "$mypassword";
 $_SESSION['sessid'] = "$cid";
 $_SESSION['sessaccid'] = "$accid";

//more code
 ?>
```

Comment: Please search the site and check the possible dupes list when typing in the title of your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR: Warning: mysql\_num\_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\....php on line 19](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045476/error-warning-mysql-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-giv)

Comment: If you're checking PHP.net for the functions, you'll already have seen the note on the manual pages which say that all the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and not recommended for use. If you're new to this, you should really be considering learning to use the up-to-date PDO library, rather than the old mysql library which means your new skills are out-of-date before you've even learnt them.

Comment: I'm new because the total amount of days I've worked with php and mysql is barely 30.Two years ago I had a project where I used php mysql and now I have another project but so little time and I'm choking, so I'm using the few things I know from the last project.
You are right all of you, I appreciate your comments and I understand because what you all say is true.

Answer (score 1):

`$result2` is returning you a boolean (meaning that an error is occurred in your select) and, so, you're passing this boolean to `mysql_result()` instead of a resource.

This is the returning value, taken from [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

You should modify your code as follow

```
[...]
$sql2="SELECT CLIENT_ID FROM $tblname WHERE USERNAME='$myusername' and PASSWORD='$mypassword'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
if($result2)
{
  $cid=mysql_result($result2,$row2); //THIS LINE!!!
}
else
{
//do some error handling
}
[...]
```

Moreover, you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions because are deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead

Comment: thank you very much!I commented weeks ago to thank you but something went wrong